# Unable to get route with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a simple products controller class, whenever I call api/products/ I get "list records" fine, but when I try to call api/products/1 I get 404 not found, what am I doing wrong.

```
namespace api.Controllers
{

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class productsController : Controller
    {




        // get record
        [HttpGet("/{id:int}")]
        public IActionResult GetRecord(int id)
        {
            return Ok("get record" + id.ToString());
        }


        // get records
        [HttpGet("/")]
        [HttpGet("")]
        public IActionResult ListRecords()
        {
            return Ok("list records");
        }



    }    
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use

```
    [HttpGet("/{id:int}")]
```

since the slash refers to the root of the path. Instead use

```
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
```

Comment: why?, isn't RESTFul compliant ??

Comment: When the path given starts with a slash, routing will treat it as the absolute path for the controller action. Without the slash, the url for the controler will be automatically prepended to the route.